# Solving diffusion from an infinite crosswind continuous line source with mathematica

Tags: differential-equations

Solving problem related to diffusion from an infinite crosswind continuous line source.

```
ClearAll
Ql = 50.;m = 0.9;n = 0.1;z1 = 0.46;K1 = 0.4;u0 = 0.01;
Kz[z_] := K1*(z/z1)^n
u[z_] := u0*(z/z1)^m
Plot[{u[z], Kz[z]}, {z, 0, 5}]
xmin = 0;
xmax = 100;
zmin = 0;
zmax = 100;

equL = u [z]* D[c[x, z], x]
equR = Kz[z]*D[c[x, z], z, z]
equ = equL == equR

bc1 = Limit[c[x, z], z -> Infinity] = 0
bc1a = Limit[c[x, z], x -> Infinity] = 0
bc2 = Limit[c[x, z], x -> 0, Direction -> -1] = Infinity
bc2a = Limit[c[x, z], z -> 0, Direction -> -1] = Infinity
bc3 = Limit[Kz[z]*D[c[x, z], z], z -> 0] = 0
bc4 = x > 0
SS[z_] = u[z]* c[x, z]
bc5 = Integate[SS[z], z, {z, 0, Infinity}] == Ql 
bc5a = Integrate[u0*c[x, z], z, {z, 0, Infinity}]
bc3a = NeumannValue[1, z == zmin];
bc4a = NeumannValue[0, z == zmax];
Clear[x]
Clear[z]
sol = NDSolve[{equ, bc1,bc1a,bc2,bc2a,bc3a,bc4a,bc5},c[x, z], {x, xmin, xmax}, {z, zmin, zmax}]
Plot3D[sol, {x, xmin, xmax}, {z, zmin, zmax}]
```

At the end it doesn't work, can anyone help me to fix it?

Comment: Can you show us the equation and corresponding b.c. in traditional math notation (using e.g. $\LaTeX$)? Currently it's not clear to me what BVP you're trying to solve.

Comment: u ∂C/∂x=(∂(K_z  ∂C/∂z))/∂z

Comment: This is PDE in math notation

Comment: What are the boundary conditions?

Comment: C→0,x,z→∞, C→∞,x=z→0, K_z  ∂C/∂z→0,z→0,x>0, i

Comment: ∫uCdz = Ql, x>0, integral 0 do Infinity, Ql is power of continous line source

Comment: What's the meaning of "x>0, i "?

Answer (score 3):

```
Ql = 50.; m = 0.9; n = 0.1; z1 = 0.46; K1 = 0.4; u0 = 0.01;
Kz[z_] := K1*(z/z1)^n
u[z_] := u0*(z/z1)^m

xmin = 0;
xmax = 100;
zmin = 0.001;
zmax = 100;

equL = u[z]*D[c[x, z], x];
equR = Kz[z]*D[c[x, z], z, z];
equ = equL - equR;

(*bc1=Limit[c[x,z],z\[Rule]Infinity]=0
bc1a=Limit[c[x,z],x\[Rule]Infinity]=0
bc2=Limit[c[x,z],x\[Rule]0,Direction\[Rule]-1]=Infinity
bc2a=Limit[c[x,z],z\[Rule]0,Direction\[Rule]-1]=Infinity
bc3=Limit[Kz[z]*D[c[x,z],z],z\[Rule]0]=0
bc4=x>0
bc5a=Integrate[u0*c[x,z],z,{z,0,Infinity}]*)

bc = NeumannValue[1, z == zmin];
bc1 = DirichletCondition[c[x, z] == 0, z == zmax];
ic = c[0, z] == 0;
sol = NDSolveValue[{equ == bc, ic, bc1}, c, {x, xmin, xmax}, {z, zmin, zmax}];
{Plot[{u[z], Kz[z]}, {z, 0, 5}, PlotLegends -> {"u", "Kz"}], 
  Plot3D[sol[x, z], {x, xmin, xmax}, {z, zmin, zmax}, 
   PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "z"}]}

(*SS[z_]=u[z]*c[x,z]
bc5=Integate[SS[z],z,{z,0,Infinity}]\[Equal]Ql*)
J = Table[{x, NIntegrate[u[z]*sol[x, z], {z, zmin, zmax}]}, {x, xmin, 
     xmax, 1}] // Quiet;

JI = Interpolation[J];

NSolve[JI[x] == Ql, x] // Quiet

{{x -> 32.3867}}
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: thank you for helping me to solve thise case

Comment: Please do you have any idea what to do with boundary condition which I take from Handbook on ATMOSPHERIC DIFFUSION, Hanna, Briggs and Hosker.

Comment: In books there are many fantastic ideas about reality on the one hand and about mathematics on the other hand. When formulating tasks, we should be guided not only by hypothetical possibilities, but also by general rules that limit the use of programs and systems such as Mathematica.